# Rails Cookie Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, browser

I have the following new method in a ruby on rails app:

```
def new
   if cookies[:owner].empty?
     cookies[:owner] = SecureRandom.hex
   end
   @movie = Movie.new
   @movie.owner = cookies[:owner]
end
```

Basically, each new user is supposed to be issued a code which identifies them (though just by the cookie). So when the user creates a movie, the cookie that was created is stored in the `owner` field.

So two problems:

1. Using the .empty? method when I delete the cookie from the browser, returns a `undefined method`empty?' for nil:NilClass`
2. When I **do** have a cookie already set in the browser, and then create a movie, the cookies[:owner] value is different from the @movie.owner code?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood well. Are you trying share the same cookie within different browsers?

Answer (score 9):

1. **cookies[:owner]** will either be `nil` (when it hasn't been set), or a String (when it's been set). The method you're looking for is `blank?`, instead of `empty?`

   ```
   2.1.0 :003 > nil.blank?
   => true

   2.1.0 :005 > "i'm not blank".blank?
   => false

   2.1.0 :006 > "       ".blank?
   => true
   ```
2. As for your second problem: where do you call the `save` method? Do you have any callback on the `Movie` model that could rewrite the `owner` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

You could also use this.

```
def new
    if !cookies[:owner]
        cookies[:owner] = SecureRandom.hex
    end
    @movie = Movie.new
    @movie.owner = cookies[:owner]
end
```